# HTML img automatically rotated

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

As you see on my [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/LYVrVNL), image is rotated by browser automatically. On the other hand if you look to [original image](https://www.truncgil.com.tr/test2.jpg) it's not rotated.

I'm using Chrome 80. I know it can be fixed on Firefox with `image-orientation` style, but how can I fix it on the chrome. I don't want the browser to rotate the image

Comment: Chrome doesn't support this tag until Chrome 81, you can check this [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=image-orientation)

Comment: I just don't want to rotation, why does it do it automatically?

Comment: Maybe this bug is relevant? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158753#c112 I've been subscribed to this bug for years now

Comment: I don't know why did they automatically rotate the image. Let the developers decide that

Comment: Did you try to convert your picture to a png and tried it againt?

Comment: @Decoolipascal yes it is fixed with it. But why do we need it?

Comment: I honestly don't know, probably a bug, as mentioned by Alon earlier.

Comment: The rotation is baked into the EXIF data of your image. This is going to be more and more common as browsers honour this EXIF setting. By converting it to a PNG you probably ended up stripping that data out of the image file.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen you're totally right. Could you please write this as answer

Comment: Absolutely, glad to help.

Comment: Interestingly on Firefox, the codepen is **not** rotated  but the raw image URL **is**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation is baked into the EXIF data of your image. This is going to be more and more common as browsers honour this EXIF setting.

As per your comment, by converting it to a PNG, you probably ended up stripping that data out of the image file, fixing the issue you were experiencing.